# Java script - return div scroll height

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, salesforce

The WebPage with particular div I need to find the vertical scroll height. Below is the code to find the entire page height, but I don't know how to calculate it with the div element.

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver
long value = (Long) executor.executeScript("return document.body.scrollHeight")

Div XPath = "//div[@class='uiScroller scroller-wrapper scroll-bidirectional native']"
```

Comment: element.offsetHeight does not work for you?

Comment: @Rediska No it's not working